# Can you generate an html report from a taskid in Sonar 5.5?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube-web

I'm finding that my sonar preview analysis (generating html report) and my sonar-scanner run (generating a taskid and indication of build-breakage) are constantly out of sync. (You can't see which issue (in the CI server) caused a particular sonar-scanner failure.

What I want to do is generate the html report (Showing the issue deltas) from the taskid that we got from the sonar-scanner run.

My question is: **Can you generate an html report from a taskid in Sonar 5.5?**

Comment: "caused a particular sonar-scanner failure"... do you mean instead "caused a particular Quality Gate failure"?

Comment: Yeah I'll go with that. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a mix of, and misunderstanding of ideas here:

- Preview analysis - runs independently of the server
- Full analysis - submits analysis report to the server
- Build breaker - returns -1 to the build job if the project fails the quality gate at the end of the (full) analysis
- HTML report - optional, additional analysis output

A preview analysis will, by nature, be "out of synch" with the server, since it doesn't submit anything back to the server. Also, since:

- a Quality Gate can only pass/fail as the result of a full analysis,
- a build can only break as the result of a failed Quality Gate (in a full analysis)

a preview analysis can't break the build.

Now let's talk about an HTML report. You can generate one as an additional output *of an analysis*, but that would have to be done *during the analysis*. It cannot happen retroactively.

Comment: Hi G. Ann - thanks for being so helpful. I'm trying to get the class that broke the build. The build-breaker won't tell me. I can tell people to look in the sonar issues list on the web server - but pre-sonar 5.1 they could just look at a locally generated html report. If I generate an html report via analysis - then it is out of synch with the build-breaker reasons. Can I get an analysis report that is in-synch with the build-breaker by analysis id?

Comment: A report will automatically be in sync with its build.